# jsPDF not generating user input

Tags: javascript, jspdf

Everything works well except for the form. I want the user to fill out the form which then creates a div with the details in it so on button click it can be captured by jsPDF:

```
inputContainer.innerHTML =
    `<h4>Email: ${inputEmail}</h4>
    <h4>Subject: ${inputSubject}</h4>
    <h4>Scorer: ${inputScorer}</h4>`
cardBody.appendChild(inputContainer);
document.getElementById('generate-btn').classList.remove('hide');
```

Then, button onclick generates PDF:

```
function getPDF() {
    let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
    let margins = {
        top:    70,
        bottom: 40,
        left:   30,
        width:  800
    };
    let source = document.getElementById("input-container");

    doc.fromHTML(source,
    margins.left, // x coord
    margins.top,
    {
      // y coord
    width: margins.width// max width of content on PDF
    }, 
    margins);
    doc.save('test.pdf');
}
```

The input-container element prints to console inside the functionPDF() but for some reason it's ignored in the PDF.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217739/jspdf-fromhtml-does-not-show-html/29218970 This might help you